# How to get module import path of a react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, bun

I'm using Bun, and I would like to get the module path from a React component.

I'm looking for something like this:

```
const myComponent = <MyComponent />

const myComponentPath = myComponent.getPath()
```

Obviously my example does not work.

How can I get the path so I could dynamically import this module later?

For example:

```
const { default: MyComponent } = await import(myComponentPath)

const myComponent = <MyComponent />
```

Comment: *"...so I could dynamically import this module later..."* What do you mean by "later"? Later during runtime? (Why would you need to dynamically import something that is already statically imported?) Later as in new code you write? (Why wouldn't you already know the path?)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder via a hydration script that will run client-side. the window object will contain a variable to the module path so it can be dynamically imported upon request

Comment: Again, why would you need to dynamically import it when it's already been statically imported? And what window object variable are you talking about? (There's also nothing about hydration in the question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean in code at runtime, you can't. The module specifier (path) isn't stored anywhere on components exported from modules.